# CodeIgniter error pages show in popup mode

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, error-handling

How can we display all types of error messages without redirecting to the error pages `application\errors\*error_pages*`
Here, We'll stay in same page and if any error occurs on action, it'll show on popup mode. 
Can anyone help me with code example ?

Comment: you will have to ajaxify your whole site.... then make a callback if error occurs whislt serving the right header from the server with the error code. it is a broad question.

Comment: you can use **$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Error Message');**

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is not clear. You can check the availability  of a 404- not found page like this:-

First open routes.php in the application/config folder and set a custom controller name.

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my404/404_page'; //my404 is class name.
```

Create a new controller and write the following code in it.

```
<?php 
  class my404 extends CI_Controller 
  {
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 

    public function 404_page() 
    { 
        // instead of loading any view just handle this response via ajax call from your client side
        $error= array();
        $error['error_code']='404';
        $error['error_message']='This url is not found';
        echo json_encode($error);
    } 
  } 
 ?>
```